# Temporary Sticky Items like 9gag

Tags: jquery, css, fixed, sticky

I search a way to make a sticky images information like [9gag.com](http://9gag.com/). (https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SuX4.png)

That not easy because the elements need to be fixed when the article are at the top of the window.

If someone know a plugin or a way to do this, that would be great :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you have search for sticky navigation bar? There are thousand of examples available. If i was not so lazy, i'd give you a link but i suspect you are lazier than me ;)  Or maybe you are not talking about a navigation bar? Is it?

Comment: I'm not talking about navigation bar..........

Comment: Ha ok, you are talking about the tweet/FB box. Sorry, didn't catch it in first in your picture. I edit your question to remove my useless downvote.

Comment: If you could provide some of your code and put it in a jsfiddle, i'm sure someone will be glad to help you. BTW, this could be a good start: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

exactly what you are looking for is here DEMO... http://jsfiddle.net/yznnJ/

Tutorial and author page is here... http://viget.com/inspire/jquery-stick-em

## CSS

```
.stickem-container {
    position: relative;
}

.stickit {
    margin-left: 660px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

.stickit-end {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.container').stickem();
});
```